# Dynamically added views are overlapping in the relativelayout

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-relativelayout

I am developing an application in which I have a `button` and on the click of that `button` I am creating a `button` *dynamically*. But the `buttons` are **overlapping**.  All I want is to avoid `overlapping` of `dynamically` created `views`.

**And in my case, use of RelativeLayout is must as I have to add Drag and Drop functionality to these dynamically created views. So no LinearLayout per se.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="AddButton"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAdd" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Button btnAddButton;
    RelativeLayout rl1;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

        btnAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
                 Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                    btn.setId(i);

                    if(i>0){
                        layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (i-1));
                    }
                    btn.setText("Button" + i);
                    rl1.addView(btn, layoutParam);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's a relative layout you need to position the new elements within the view using LayoutParams. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: Simply take a LinearLayout and set it orientation horizontal ..new element will be in right of the other and if something occurs addRule to it..

Comment: @Nepster, the thing is that  we are required to use `RelativeLayout` as later we want to apply `Drag` `and` `Drop` to these views. `LinearLayout` will just allow us to move vertically or horizontally and not otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add rule to your relative layout's parameters for that:

```
btnAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i++;
        Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        btn.setId(i);
        if(i>0){
            layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (i-1));
        }
        btn.setText("Button" + i);
        rl1.addView(btn, layoutParam);

    }
});
```

This way, your buttons will be laid out on right of last button.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Try to take your LayoutParams inside loop.
This is working fine for me:

```
RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn.setId(i);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (i > 0) {
        layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (i - 1));
    }

    btn.setText("Button" + i);
    rl1.addView(btn, layoutParam);  
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT**

Even if you don't use loop, and add in button click, it should work:

```
int i = 1;
//this is a method being called on button's click:
public void add(View v) {
    Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn.setId(i);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (i > 1) {

        layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (i - 1));
    }

    btn.setText("Button" + i);
    rl1.addView(btn, layoutParam);
    i++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: LayoutParams layoutParam;
I have used it with your code but still i'm getting error

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
i've used it as well but still the buttons are overlapping.

Comment: Used `layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (i-1));`? @hanishsharma

Comment: Then may be some issue in id. Please debug. @hanishsharma else update question with new code and screenshot..

Comment: It is adding button 1 2 3 simultaneously.
and my requirement is button 1 at the click of button 1 then button 2 then 3 and so on..
so that user can add so many buttons according to the need

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve the issue.

**Hide button and show it on click**

No need to add the button dynamically . Just add two button one is visible and other invisible. And on click of **btnAddButton** simply show it..

```
      otherBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      otherBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// you can also set it in xml by visiblity="true"
```

**Use LinearLayout instead**

Take a `LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout` it automatically add it to the right after setting it orientation and if it is not set then addRule as suggested by @Dhruti

Comment: **Hide button and show it on click** <-- This won't solve our main motive. We must make all the views dynamically or else it will be too heavy as we need such views for almost all the widgets.